# Enterprise Wiki site has categories webpart greyed out. Powershell solution

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have a problem with a webpart called "Wiki Categories". It is greyed out when in edit mode. I have read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_2010/archive/2011/05/13/enterprise-wiki-site-has-categories-webpart-greyed-out.aspx) topic to solve the problem, and it's correct. But I need to solve this via powershell commands. 
I tried to do the same as I read at the topic above. So I set to the Wiki Categories site column the following:

```
$column.SspId = $SspId
$column.TermSetId = $TermSetId
```

After that if I navigate to Site Settings > Site Columns > Wiki Categories I see that the term is used now. But the webpart still remain greyed out. I have no idea why...

Appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: Are those properties read/write? Typically you would set the value of a property as the new variable.
Such as: 
`$SsId = $column.SspId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found why the webpart remained greyed out. I just needed to use the `SPField.Update` method with parameter `$true`.

Here is the code example for those who want to resolve this issue with sharepoint powershell:

```
$web= Get-SPWeb your.sharepoint.site
$WikiCategory = "YourCategory" 
$ColumnName = "Wiki Categories"

$session = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site) 
$termStores = $session.TermStores

$SspId = $termStores[0].Id

function GetTermSetId($termStores) 
{ 
foreach ($termstore in $termStores[0].Groups) 
{ 
$TermSetId = $termstore.TermSets[$WikiCategory].Id 
return $TermSetId 
} 
}

$TermSetId = GetTermSetId($termStores)

$contentType = $web.ContentTypes["Enterprise Wiki Page"] 
$column = $web.Fields[$ColumnName] 
$fieldLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink($column) $contentType.FieldLinks.Add($fieldLink) 
$contentType.Update()

$column.SspId = $SspId 
$column.TermSetId = $TermSetId 
$column.Required = $false 
$column.EnforceUniqueValues = $false 
$column.Group = "Custom Columns" 
$column.Update($true) 
$web.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be an error related to the MMS service. Have a look here (URL http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_2010/archive/2011/05/13/enterprise-wiki-site-has-categories-webpart-greyed-out.aspx) to see if it helps.